# Какая нужна библиотека, чтобы работать с датами, строками и цветами в с++?

Tags: c++

Хочу объявить переменные или массивы которые будут хранить даты, цвета, строки.

На оболочке mql4 я так и пишу: datetime, color, string, а здесь ничего не происходит при указании этих типов данных?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, Прошу прощения, видимо, я неправильно понял.

Comment: Потому что поставили ограничения и создали условия при которых я не могу ставить нормальные корректные метки и предложения, выбрать эти метки меня заставила схема. Могу сказать что портал очень дурной всякие ограничения и прочий бред. Тут даже сообщения сложно писать.

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с датой можете использовать `std::chrono`, строки - `std::string`.
Для этого нужно подключить: `#include <chrono>` и `#include<string>` 
Для хранения параметров цвета можете написать свою структуру или класс, который будет хранить нужные Вам данные, в зависимости от поставленной задачи либо численное представление цвета, либо в виде строки. Вот можете посмотреть [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39662339/what-is-a-good-way-to-store-color)

Comment: Со строками справился. С цветом не разобрался но понял что сложная специфика. С датами возникли проблемы. Библиотеку #include <chrono> берёт, а эту запись using std::chrono; не берёт. Я немного про это всё читал я думал тоже нужно как с цветом муть структуру для ней, минут, секунд. Как будет объявляться  переменная хранящая дату. Мне нужно чтобы переменная хранила дату вот так 2001.10.19 00:00.

Comment: Почитайте о библиотеке ```<chrono>```, свою структуру вы создать можете, для хранения времени, но обрабатывать это без ```<chono>``` или ```<ctime>``` будет крайне затруднительным процессом.